# Merge Replication : Column 'rowguid' in table 'TableName' is invalid for creating a default constraint

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am using merge replication to synchronize data between two databases. It creates a new column in each article table 'rowguid'. At the time of sync, it is throwing error:

> Column 'rowguid' in table 'TableName' is invalid for creating a default constraint.

I have tried recreating the publication & subscribers but no luck.

Comment: Ankush, this is not a programming problem. I am setting up merge-replication through sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try to create the replication snapshot again... After this operation synchronization should work

Comment: I tried recreating the replication snapshot again, still not working. I am not including all the tables for replication because I need only few tables to be synced....can it cause the problem?

Comment: If you remove the replica, the column rowguid is dropped from tables or not?